# Web app with SensorTag CC2650

Tags: javascript, sensors, phonegap

I'm creating a web application using the SensorTag CC2650 for my thesis. I have to use Phonegap to create this app, and I found a very good repository where there are some example of how to show the results of the sensors.

http://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

I have one problem; in the examples there are no clear references about how to get data from humidity and light sensor. I wrote to the developer, and I search in the Texa site if there were any documentation that could help me, but I didn't find anything.
I also search in the web, but I didn't found a lot. Most of them was about Android&IOS project.

Does anyone know how to get this parameters? The only thing I found are the declaration of the variables, in the technical documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the correct BLE services/characteristics. The readme for the SensorTag can be found here:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User%27s_Guide#Optical_Sensor

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User%27s_Guide#Humidity_Sensor

And a quick lookup table for all the UUIDs of the services/characteristics can be found here: http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/538/attr_5F00_cc2650-sensortag.html

So looking at the documentation for the cordova plugin it would be:

```
ble.read(device_id, service_uuid, characteristic_uuid, success, failure);
```

And take the UUIDs from the previous table.